# Ways of verifying a phone number

Tags: authentication, sms, voip, voice

Hi im working on a phone number based android app,
Im currently using google firebase.
Google firebase is pretty expensive when it comes to phone authentication,
I was thinking if there are any other ways to authenticate a phone number.
Programmable sms like twilio is fairly  cheaper but still pretty expensive for my budget.
Is it possible to use voip to auth a phone number?
Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Using twilio is right option for limited number of sms for your purpose, as for voip they all depend on SMS gateways, and to have gateway which may be cheaper but require massive sms, as they are more expensive.